# iOS/Swift 1.2 NSDictionray/Dictionary on NSStandardUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

In the 'old' Swift, I used to register my defaults loaded from a .plist file like this...

```
let prefs = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("UserDefaults", ofType: "plist");
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: prefs!);
let defaults:NSDictionary! = dict?.valueForKey("defaults") as! NSDictionary;

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defaults);
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

Under Swift 1.2, I get the error...

*Cannot invoke 'registerDefaults' with an argument list of type '(NSDictionary!)'*

So, something has changed and Swift no-longer accepts an NSDictionary as a parameter to registerDefaults.

So, how can I convert my NSDictionary to a Dictionary object, given that they're no-longer interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a type cast from `NSDictionary` to a `[NSObject:AnyObject]` -

use

```
let prefs = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("UserDefaults", ofType: "plist");
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: prefs!);
let defaults:NSDictionary! = dict?.valueForKey("defaults") as! NSDictionary
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defaults as [NSObject : AnyObject]);
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

Comment: Thanks.  It was the conversion that was my 'struggle'.  Sorted and working!

Comment: No problem.  If you remove the ! from `let defaults:NSDictionary! = ...` then Xcode actually suggests the fix for you.  It is the explicitly unwrapped optional that throws it for some reason

Comment: Ha...you're right. I think I tried every combination and 'auto-correct' option, but missed that one. I suppose sometimes blind panic sets in  :)

Comment: question, in your defaults:Dictionary declaration is the valueForKey("defaults") the name of one of the line items in the pList? I'm getting nil when unwrapping. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The user defaults can store NSDictionary objects. These are mapped to Swift as [NSObject : AnyObject]:

Try this:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(defaults, forKey: "defaults")
var isOk = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

Comment: Thanks...that 'worked' in that it compiled and ran but it didn't actually register my defaults.

Comment: This code will store your `defaults` dictionary under a single key in "defaults", which isn't what you want