# How do I register a plist to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, plist, nsuserdefaults

What I'm trying to do is store my initial user defaults in a plist and then read them into NSUserDefaults when the application loads for the first time.

I've found a couple of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646193/ios-swift-1-2-nsdictionray-dictionary-on-nsstandarduserdefaults/29646602#29646602) which have helped me thus far however I can't seem to find an answer as to why I'm finding nil while unwrapping. Obviously I'm missing something, so my question is:

**How do I properly register a plist to NSUserDefaults?**

I've created a plist with my default settings. I'd like to read from the plist and register them into NSUserDefaults.

**settings.plist**

[image]

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let prefs = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist")
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: prefs!)

        if let dictionary = dict {
            println("Contents of file unwrapped: \(dictionary)") // <---------
            let defaults : NSDictionary! = dictionary.valueForKey("Root") as? NSDictionary
            println("defaults: \(defaults)") // <---------
            userDefaults.registerDefaults(defaults as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
            userDefaults.synchronize()
        }

        if let unwrapDict = dict {

            var myValue = unwrapDict.objectForKey("Boolean Switch 1") as! Bool
            println("pulled from pList \(myValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure you've noticed that I am looking for the key 'Root' from my plist...

```
let defaults : NSDictionary! = dictionary.valueForKey("Root") as? NSDictionary
```

I have also tried passing it other values like "Boolean Switch 1" and casting to different types. But nothing I try changes the outcome.

Here's my console output from the two `println()` logs.

[image]

Comment: your dictionary doesn't have a "Root" key, as you can see from your log. The dictionary you created is the root dictionary that you see in your plist.

Comment: I was updating my post in reference to that actually. I have tried passing it "Boolean Switch 1" as well and that fails too. I am assuming I need to pass it an entire dictionary that's why I tried passing it Root.

Comment: Doing `let defaults : NSDictionary! = dictionary.valueForKey("Boolean Switch 1") as? NSDictionary` will return a nil as well because a NSDictionary isn't at that key value. The `as?` enforces that the object is a dictionary or nil if it isn't. `let defaults : NSDictionary! = dictionary.valueForKey("Boolean Switch 1") as? NSNumber` should give you the number from the plist.

Comment: This returns and error: NSNumber is not convertible to NSDictionary...

Comment: remove the `: NSDictionary!` after defaults. In swift, you do not need to declare the type of the object you are creating if you are using `as` to enforce type.

Comment: that helped, I got the code running but I still have a lot of questions, I wound up posting my code on Code Review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87260/registering-a-plist-to-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a day of messing with this code I was able to finally get my plist entered into NSUserDefaults. I wasn't satisfied with the final outcome because I noticed that the `registerDefaults` wasn't actually *doing* anything.

So I decided to post my working code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87260/registering-a-plist-to-nsuserdefaults) to see if there were any parts of my code that weren't necessary. It turns out that `registerDefualts` indeed was not necessary, here's an excerpt from the [Alex's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/67132/alex) answer to my question.

> This line: 
>   userDefaults.registerDefaults(dict as! [NSObject : AnyObject])  does
>   not actually set the information on the NSUserDefaults storage file on
>   disk. All it does is tell NSUserDefaults the default values to be used
>   when a key doesn't yet exist on disk.

So having said all of that, I'll post the working code. I should note, as it was pointed out to me by [nhgrif](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/36366/nhgrif), that the ViewController is really **not** the place to put this code and a better place is in the appDelegate in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.

**ViewController:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let prefs = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist")
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: prefs!)
        userDefaults.setObject(dict, forKey: "defaults")          
        userDefaults.synchronize()

        // this just toggles the aBool value
        if let defaults = userDefaults.valueForKey("aBool") as? NSNumber {

            if defaults as NSObject == 1 {
                println("inside the conditional: \(defaults)")
                userDefaults.setValue(0, forKey: "aBool")
                userDefaults.synchronize()
                println("Setting aBool to true")
            } else {
                userDefaults.setValue(1, forKey: "aBool")
                userDefaults.synchronize()
                println("setting aBool to false")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need, you can store data to custom UserDefaults directly like; `UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "Settings")?.set(2.0, forKey: "version")` and read the value like `UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "Settings")?.value(forKey: "version") as? String ?? "0.0"`

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple document, If you don't change any value on settings, Values reading from NSUserDefaults are nil or 0. In your code, When you read a value from NSUserDefaults, you should set it a default value.

Comment: hmm, I thought they were set in the plist prior... I'll read about how to set a default value and give that a shot

Comment: seems like the problem is with this line: let defaults : NSDictionary! = dictionary.valueForKey("Boolean Switch 1") as? NSDictionary it comes back as nil but it exists in my plist